# decrease bar spacing chartJS v2

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I would draw a thick bars with a small spacing

Actually when I decrease bar thinckess I get gap between bars.

What I would is to decrease this gap like in the photo

[image: What I expect]

And here's what Actually I have

[image: What I actually have]

Here's a [reproduction](https://jsfiddle.net/07pzys9t/2/)

```
var options = {
    responsive: false,
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    animation: {
        animateScale: true
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            barThickness: 45
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            barPercentage: 1,
            categoryPercentage: 1,
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    },
    tooltips: {

    }
};
var dataForChart = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [0.2, 0.4, .78, 0.05],
        backgroundColor: ["#FF6384",
            "#4BC0C0",
            "#FFCE56",
            "#36A2EB"
        ],
        borderWidth: 0
    }],
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
};
var chart = new Chart($("#statsRenderingResultsDeliveryClaimsChart"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: dataForChart,
    options: options
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a chart helper API which stores all the instances of a chart for a particular page. You can make use of that to find out if there is nothing present then create logic else update logic.

See the sample below. This is not the most refined logic but just to give an idea.

```
 var chartUpdated  = false;

Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function(instance) {
  if (instance.chart.canvas.id === "yourCanvasId") {
    //perform the update logic
    chartUpdated = true;
    return;
  }  
});

if(!chartUpdated)
{
    //perform the create logic
}
```